# Android Studio Take Picture in Fragment doesn't work

Tags: android, image, android-fragments, camera, onactivityresult

I'm trying to set a Profilepicture with a picture that you can take before. This happends in a Fragment. My Code up so far is:

```
public class ProfileFragment extends Fragment {

CircleImageView profilepicture;

private static final int CAM_REQUEST = 1313;
public ProfileFragment() {
    // Required empty public constructor
}

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // Inflate the layout for this fragment
    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_profile, container, false);

    profilepicture = (CircleImageView) view.findViewById(R.id.profilepicture);
    return view;
}

public void profilepictureOnClick(){
    takeNewProfilePicture();
}

@Override
public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

    if(resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK) {
        if(requestCode == CAM_REQUEST){
            Bitmap thumbnail = (Bitmap) data.getExtras().get("data");
            profilepicture.setImageBitmap(thumbnail);
        }
    }
}

private void takeNewProfilePicture(){
    Intent cameraintent = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
    startActivityForResult(cameraintent, CAM_REQUEST);
}

}
```

If i run this like that, the App shows, after i accepted the picture, the "first" Fragment, not the Profilefragment and when i go back to the profilefragment, the profilepicture hasn't changed. I already set breakpoints and went through it in Debug Mode: The Programm stops at a breakpoint, but when i click "step over", it's like it reloads, but it's still at the same breakpoint...

Any Ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Use the following code:

```
private void takeNewProfilePicture(){
   Fragment profileFrag = this;
   Intent cameraintent = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
   profileFrag.startActivityForResult(cameraintent, CAM_REQUEST);
}
```

In your parent activity, override onActivityResult() like this:

```
 @Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    }
```

**Here what is actually happening:** onActivityResult() is handled by activity. In your previous code, when you called startActivityForResult(), Activity was thinking it is getting request from previous fragment. So You have to specify from which fragment startActivityForResult is calling. That's what has been done in the above code.

Hope this helps.

Comment: hey @tahsinRupam, first thank you try to help. I used your code but the result is exactly the same

Comment: From where the method profilepictureOnClick() is called. You can provide your activity class, it may clear things a bit.

Comment: I'm a work right now, can't test it. I will test it as soon as i can and than respond here :)

Comment: Oh sure, Sorry to disturb you :(